# Connect Excel Slicer With Multiple PivotTables Using Python

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to connect my slicer 1 with other pivot tables via Python win32com. I am unable to run my code successfully and get the below error message. The 4th line below is what gives an error.

What do I need to do to add my slicer connection to the other pivot table?

**ADD IN SLICER 1:**

```
 slicer_cache1 = wb.SlicerCaches.Add2(PivotTable1,'NAME')   
 slicer1 = slicer_cache1.Slicers.Add(SlicerDestination = b_charts,Name ='NAME',Caption = 'NAME',Top = 1,Left = 750,Width =600,Height=250)  
 slicer1.NumberOfColumns = 3
 slicer_cache1.PivotTables.AddPivotTable(PivotTable2)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Exception has occurred: com_error

(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)

File "C:\\Users\\...\\3.11\\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\\SlicerPivotTables.py", line 33, in AddPivotTable return self.\_oleobj\_.InvokeTypes(2990, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((9, 1),),PivotTable ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\\Users\\...\\test.py", line 163, in \<module\> slicer_cache1.PivotTables.AddPivotTable(PivotTable2) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

I tried `slicer_cache1.PivotTables.AddPivotTable(PivotTable2)` and it did not work. I got this from the internet and from recording a macro in Excel and trying to translate it to Python.

Comment: The issue was the pivot tables were using different wb.PivotCaches(). Once I used the same for all three, I was able to use a modified version of the above last line.